# Can't see Swift object hierarchy in debug area when used within Objective-C class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, debugging

My problem may be so simple but I'm so lost in it.
Any comment, idea, help, prediction would be so useful.

Here are my classes

> TrialSwiftClass.swift

```
import Foundation

@objc public class TrialSwiftClass : NSObject{
    var first : String?
    var second : NSString?
    var third : NSNumber = 0


    override init(){
        super.init()
    }

    init(data:NSArray){

            self.first = data[0] as? String
            self.second = data[1] as? NSString
            self.third = data[2] as! NSNumber
    }
}
```

> TrialObjectiveCClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TrialObjectiveCClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *first;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *second;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *third;

- (instancetype)initWithArray:(NSArray *)data;

@end
```

> TrialObjectiveCClass.m

```
#import "TrialObjectiveCClass.h"

@implementation TrialObjectiveCClass


- (instancetype)initWithArray:(NSArray *)data{
    self.first = data[0];
    self.second = data[1];
    self.third = data[2];

    return self;
}
@end
```

Now here comes the problem.When I use these two classes in my ViewController.m which has following code in it:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TrialObjectiveCClass.h"
#import "Codemaster-Swift.h" //Automatically created header to use Swift code in Objective-C


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *trialArray = @[@"FirstString", @"SecondString", @99];


    //First the Swift part
    TrialSwiftClass *obj = [[TrialSwiftClass alloc] initWithData:trialArray];

    NSLog(@"%@", obj.first);
    NSLog(@"%@", obj.second);
    NSLog(@"%@", obj.third);


    //Now the Objective-C part
    TrialObjectiveCClass *obj2 = [[TrialObjectiveCClass alloc] initWithArray:trialArray];
    NSLog(@"%@", obj2.first);
    NSLog(@"%@", obj2.second);
    NSLog(@"%@", obj2.third);


}
```

If I put a breakpoint in the last NSLog in ViewController.m, here is what i see in debug area:
[image]

My logs are showing the right value of my object's properties.

Why can't i see the hierarchy of my Swift class but can see my Objective-C class? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variables in your Swift class get exposed to ObjC as properties.  At present the Locals view does not show the properties of an object, only its ivars.  This is true regardless of whether the class comes from ObjC or Swift.  That's why the swift variables don't show up in the locals view.

You can work around this by using the expression command in the lldb console to view the object's properties.  For instance, stopped in your example, you can do:

```
(lldb) expr obj.first
(__NSCFConstantString *) $0 = 0x00000001002d1498 @"FirstString"
```

etc.

Comment: Clearest explanation 

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the hierarchy of your Swift class in that point. When you bridge your swift class to an obj-c file something happening and the debugger can't see anymore your properties. This is a bug or something else, I can't figure out yet. But if you would like to see your hierarchy you can see that in your Swift file.

[image]

[image]

Another solution if you create a swift project and initialize there the objective-c classes. So if you can create on the opposite way,  the properties and hierarchy will appear in the debug field.

[image]

This is not an explanation for that, why your solution not working but I hope this will help you a little bit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but think about a situation when it comes to debug some nested objects in an array. While going into each class and seeing the inner sides of objects you have to keep in mind the relation between this objects, their indexes in your array etc.And it is nearly impossible to debug in this way when it comes to parse a complicated JSON response to Swift objects in an Objective-C class.Also it would be good to know for sure if this is a bug or something I do wrong.

Comment: You did not do anything wrong, if you just use pure swift or pure objective-c everything will work fine. This is a mixed up situation not everything will work properly in this.

Comment: Okay, I will try to find out a more specific answer for you.