# Swift Obj-c Model

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, debugging

I would like to see a Objective-c model in swift. But I have this problem:

[image]

I can´t display the content although it´s right.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244331/cant-see-swift-object-hierarchy-in-debug-area-when-used-within-objective-c-clas Same problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I'm not doing anything wrong, it's failure xcode.